# Code coverage without junit

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

Is it possible to use jacoco in sonar without writing junit as I have added jacoco plugin in sonarqube but when I ran the sonar scanner then it is showing 0% code coverage. Please advise me on this as I am new to this work.

Comment: Nope, You cannot measure code coverage for tests, without executing the tests.

Answer (score 6):

JaCoCo is a coverage tool that will record, during an execution of the Junit test where the execution went through your code.

So short answer is : **no**. This makes absolutely no sense.

(this is a bit simplified but given the question I am keeping things short here).

Answer (score 0):

you can use jacoco java agent, which has nothing to do with junit, and just run your code, then report the code coverage. See this doc for more details

https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html